# What is the exact verb in this sentence and how is it being used?

Tags: single-word-request

Is the verb in this sentence "zu jemandem sehen in etw."? I couldn't understand.

"Eine Parallele zwischen den Mikroben bei Wells und der menschlichen Vernunft sieht zu Guttenberg darin, dass beide Phänomene klein und unsichtbar sind."

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue might just be the former nobility name "zu Guttenberg": The word *zu* is just part of the name, like *van* in "Ludwig van Beethoven" or *von* in "John von Neumann".

So "zu Guttenberg" is the subject of the sentence, everything before the verb "sieht" is an accusative object. The basic idiom here is "etwas *(accusative)* in etwas *(dative)* sehen". I think this exists in English as well.

> Zu Guttenberg sees a parallel between ... in the fact that ...